# Bash command: head

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

I am trying to find all files with `dummy*` in the folder named `dummy`. Then I need to sort them according to time of creation and get the 1st 10 files. The command I am trying is:

```
find -L /home/myname/dummy/dummy* -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | head -n 10 -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

But this doesn't seem to work with the following error:

```
head: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'head --help' for more information.
```

How do I make the bash to not read `-exec` as part of `head` command?

UPDATE1:

Tried the following:

`find -L /home/myname/dummy/dummy* -maxdepth 0 -type f  -exec readlink -f {} \; -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | head -n 10`

But this is not according to timestamp sort because both find and printf are printing the files and sort is sorting them all together.

Files in dummy are as follows:
dummy1, dummy2, dummy3 etc. This is the order in which they are created.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understood that `-exec` is not a valid option for `head`. Hence the UPDATE1. Please check it

Comment: You are going about this in a very convoluted manner, by the way.  Given that you are assuming anyway that the filenames do not contain newlines, it would be a lot easier to use `ls -cr` than `find` + `sort` + `cut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make the bash to not read -exec as part of head command?

The `-exec` and subsequent arguments appear intended to be directed to `find`.  The `find` command stops at the first `|`, so you would need to move those arguments ahead of that:

```
find -L /home/myname/dummy/dummy* -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' -exec readlink -f {} \; | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | head -n 10
```

However, it doesn't make much sense to **both** `-printf` file details and `-exec readlink` the results.  Possibly you wanted to run `readlink` on each filename that makes it past `head`. In that case, you might want to look into the `xargs` command, which serves exactly the purpose of converting data read from the standard input into arguments to a command.  For example:

```
find -L /home/myname/dummy/dummy* -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
  sort -n |
  cut -d' ' -f 2- |
  head -n 10 |
  xargs -rd '\n' readlink -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating things here. Using just `ls` and `head` should get you the results you want:

`ls -lt /home/myname/dummy/dummy* | head -10`

To sort by ctime specifically, use the `-c` flag for `ls`:

`ls -ltc /home/myname/dummy/dummy* | head -10`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sometimes I may not be able to give the entire file path. I do need to use `find` and not `ls`